# Cannot change the permission to 600 in iMac

Tags: macos, chmod

I just found that I cannot change the permissions settings in my iMac. The group and other permissions are always the same as the user permissions, so when I type:

```
chmod 600 a.txt
```

the permissions will become

```
-rw-rw-rw-  1 chaol1  owner           0 Oct 18 19:43 a.txt
```

If I use - to delete the permissions of group and other, it will not delete them.

Comment: Where is this file located?  You might need to use sudo.  And did you try "chmod 0600 a.txt"?

Comment: or try `chmod u=rw,g=,o= a.txt && echo $?` ?

Comment: the file is put in a normal directory, and I have tried both of your suggestions, they donot work

Comment: Is this on some sort of alternate/removable/USB drive with a FAT filesystem?